# What is the best way to let the commuity know that a question is not good?

Tags: discussion, questions, question-quality

Being an active user, I know there are various ways to let the community know that a question is not good, or does not fit the community guidelines.

1. **Vote down:** By voting down we can let the person who asked question know that there is 
   something which needs to be improved.
2. **Flag:** Using flags, we can let moderators know that this question needs some extra attention.
3. **Vote to Close:** A user with the right permissions can vote to close a question.
4. **Leave comments.**

*If there are any others, please add them here.*

Which of the above is the best? When exactly should we use one or another way to inform the community that there is something wrong with a question?

Comment: How about leaving a comment? This sounds more to the point and describes exactly what could be wrong, IMO.

Comment: Simplest way is a downvote. Or fix the question

Comment: *Which of the above is the best*: That depends on the question. This question, for example, is lacking in context, so I downvoted it *and* voted to close it as 'unclear what you are asking'. It does not need moderator attention (I can handle this myself, no need to involve a moderator, it's not unreadable and unsalvageable or spam or requiring migration, for example).

Comment: I did leave a comment here though; to let the OP know how they could improve the question, or to give a quick pointer that's not worthy of an answer, etc. There can be many reasons to comment, again that depends on the context.

Comment: Last but not least, you can *edit* the question to improve the formatting, add new detail the OP put in the comments, etc. Again, this is context sensitive.

Comment: You are not limited to just one of these actions.  In fact, you often *won't* be doing just one.  They are primarily orthogonal functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your motivation to let the community know a **question** isn't good is admirable, but it shouldn't be your top priority. Your top priority should be to **make the question better**. This might involve editing it yourself, or leaving comments for the OP asking questions and suggesting more information that should be edited into the question.

Some people like to also downvote, perhaps to motivate the OP to improve the question, or to punish the OP for asking a bad question, or to make it simpler to delete the question later.

If there is no way the question can be improved (for example, a cooking question on SO or a C++ question on Seasoned Advice) then it makes sense to vote to close it. You may also vote to close really poor questions to stop others from answering them while they need improvement, or as a way station towards deleting the question. If you're not able to vote to close, or if the problems are so serious a moderator should step in to help, you might flag the question.

Only once you know a question is not going to get any better should you start to worry about warning "the community" about its quality. A downvote and/or a comment are the tools in that case. But don't start with "hey everyone, bad question here!" Start with **making it better**.

(Answers are different. An answer can be written and formatted perfectly, and completely represent the authors thoughts on the matter, be well understood by everyone who reads it, and still be wrong. The urge to make an answer better should be resisted in most cases. Downvote it, comment on it, add another answer of your own. Maybe flag, maybe. But this is about questions.)